# How to navigate to another view in NavigationView without NavigationButton in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

As the questions says I want to navigate to another view without NavigationButton, something like "pushView" and "popView" in UIkit

Comment: alternate you can use with `PresentationButton`

Comment: I don't think there's another way (yet) to push/pop views

Comment: `PresentationButton` is correct answer as @Anbu.Karthik said.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `NavigationButton`?

Comment: @Fogmeister Because I want to do a request to the server when the button is pressed and navigate to the next view after I get the response from the server, but I did not manage how to do that with a NavigationButton, only with Button :(

Comment: Adding on, there are a lot of use cases where I might want an action in one place in an app to add a view to the main navigation hierarchy, without a corresponding button. For example, after creating a record I might want to transition to the detail view for that record right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I consider this more like a work-around for a limitation, but it worked for me:

Add a boolean state variable which defines whether the link is active. E.g.:

```
@State private var showLinkTarget = false
```

Add an invisible NavigationLink like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: LinkTargetView(), isActive: self.$showLinkTarget ) {
   Spacer().fixedSize() 
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this logic only works once in my case

Comment: Alternatively use EmptyView instead of Spacer().fixedSize()

Comment: If it only works once, did you made sure that you set showLinkTarget to false again on return?