# Navigate conditionally with NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to perform a web request when clicking on a `NavigationLink`, and depending of whether the response is success or failure, navigate to a new view with the success data, or stay in the current one (showing an error notification).

I tried:

- `isActive` attribute: While this allows me to activate the navigation programmatically, it doesn't prevent the navigation triggered by the UI.
- `simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded({...}))`: This allows me to perform actions when navigating, but I can't prevent the navigation from happening here either.
- `disabled` modifier: This makes the `NavigationLink` not interactive.

Alternatively I could implement a plain button, with a hidden `NavigationLink` and `isActive`, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58571175/930450). It doesn't seem ideal but it probably works.

Better suggestions? I'm aware that I also could do the web request in the new view, but this isn't good UX IMO.

Comment: If the user presses a button/navigationlink I believe they expect to open a new view *immediately*. Delaying it would probably be an even worse UX design. But isn't it all *opinion-based*?

Comment: I agree with @pawello2222.  You should transition to the next view immediately and show some kind of loading animation if the network access could be delayed.  If the network access fails to produce the desired data, put up an error alert and when they accept it, pop back to the previous view.

Comment: "If the user presses a button they expect to open a new view immediately": Why would they do that? It's just a submit button. They expect that it submits the data. The navigation to a success screen if the submission succeeds is an optional follow-up.

Comment: @Ixx The *submit* button may be an exception - you didn't explain it before. In this case the usual solution is *Button+HiddenNavigationLink*.

Comment: @pawello2222 I don't think it's an exception. Applies to any action where you want to perform some sort of validation / request first. SwiftUI's api likely will be updated at some point to support better programmatic navigation, as this is obviously lacking.